# Why can you only have one root user terminal process running at a time?

Tags: apt, root

This question was asked out of mostly curiosity.

I've just flashed a new SD card with Rasbian Stretch Lite and when I did, little did I know that Stretch Lite is very similar to Arch Linux Arm. And Arch Linux is all about being as minimal as possible.

So then, I found myself having a very long line of package installations. Too bad that when I tried to have three Terminals running `sudo apt-get install packagename` at the same time Linux kept on telling me that "some other process has locked down sudo."

What? Why?

This is really just a general question: The simplified question would be as to why "you can't have more than one root terminal process running at once?" Think installing multiple software packages, like I tried to do.

Comment: no problems running sudo on multiple "terminals" - are you sure the error isn't regarding apt-get? because that can only have one instance in most cases

Comment: @JaromandaX This just really a general question. That software installation problem was just an example

Comment: that software installation problem is because you can only have one instance of `apt-get` running ... there is no limit to how many `sudo` are in effect at any time - so, the question is flawed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have as many `root` terminals as you like. I'm pretty sure the actual error message you saw is not what you've put in the question.

What you can't do is running several instances of `apt` running in parallel on the same installation. `apt` keeps information in several files which have to be updated coherently, so the first instance you run will create a lockfile preventing subsequent instances from running.